# Where is the mount point of an SMB share mounted by Nautilus on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba, 22.04

I've mounted a NAS on my local network using nautilus in Ubuntu 22.04 and I can't find the mount point.

I used to do this in Ubuntu 20.04 and find it in `/run/user/1000/gvfs` but there's nothing there. `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` resolves to the same dir.

Copying the path of a folder in the share (or hovering over it) in nautilus just gives me a smb url e.g.:
`smb://nas.local/dir1/dir2`

I can't figure out any way to navigate to this dir in a terminal.

Comment: Might be more practical to mount the NAS in fstab where you can control where it is mounted. https://linuxhint.com/mount-smb-shares-on-ubuntu/

Comment: With what command, or through what method have you "mounted" the NAS? Are you sure you have _mounted_ it, and not just connected phisycally? Maybe it is not _actually_ mounted yet? There is a difference between a device being merely connected, and a filesystem on that device being explicitly mounted in your filesystem.

Comment: @Levente I assumed it was mounted since I'm browsing it in nautilus, but indeed you might be right that it isn't, it's certainly what the symptom looks like.

Comment: @24601 I worked around it with that approach, thanks.

Comment: I've added that as an answer with further information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might be more practical to mount the NAS in the `/etc/fstab` file itself where you can more easily control where it is mounted and the other mount options you wish to invoke as well.

There is a [useful link here](https://linuxhint.com/mount-smb-shares-on-ubuntu/) concerning mounting SMB shares on Ubuntu.

I have used these procedures successfully for mounting Synology NAS shares in versions 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS and more recently 22.04 LTS with the following line in `fstab`

```
//192.168.1.117/[share-name] /media/NAS/[share_name] cifs username=[user],password=[psw],rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

(replace the items in square brackets with your own credentials and the IP address you wish to use on your system)

Comment: Hovering over it just gives "smb://nas.local/dir1"

Answer (score 0):

If you did not remove gnome-terminal, when you right-click on nautilus you should see an option "Open in terminal". After the terminal is opened, you should see the path on the terminal.

If you did remove gnome-terminal and do not want to reinstall it, you can add a nautilus script to open a terminal of your choice that starts on that directory.

The script goes to `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/name_of_the_script`. The script should be executable, so run `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/name_of_the_script` after you've created the script.

This script is for `terminator`, if you choose to use a different terminal emulator, you should adjust the 3rd line accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="$(pwd | sed 's/[ ]/\ /g')"
terminator --working-directory="$directory"
```

Comment: "Open In Terminal" is available for local dirs in nautilus but not when I'm browsing the smb dir. Thanks for the script, also works in local dirs, but when I try it for the smb one the terminal just opens in my home dir! What is going on!?